# How to build an own www-server?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver

I'm an unemployed person and I thought I would like to build my personal homepage to the Internet and put my portfolio there. How hard is it to set my laptop to work as a personal WWW-server? Is it possible to set it so that for example everyone sees for example the directory `/var/www` but only I can see other directories? Or do I need another computer as a server and another for my own projects?

I'm relatively newcomer with computers but I can use Ubuntu via command line and via desktop.

Comment: Good on you for being creative in finding employment - depending on your circumstances you may find it far easier to use a free website builder such as www.weebly.com or www.wix.com which can look very profesional at a fraction of the effort.

Comment: "Is it possible to set it so that for example everyone sees for example the directory /var/www but only I can see other directories?"  This is not only possible, it is the *normal* behaviour with any webserver package.  That doesn't mean it is not possible to expose directories you did not intend to due to misconfiguration or software bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively speaking: Easy, depending on your ability.

While this is a very broad question, I'll try to give you the basic run down of what's needed.

1. Webserver software. There are many to pick from, but I've found apache and lighttpd to be the simplest ones, depending on your long-term goals. You set up which directories your webserver serves as root for the website. It can also have multiple roots serving multiple websites.
2. Some way for others to connect to your laptop. You most likely do not have a static IP address at home, so you will probably have to rely on a dynamic DNS provider. This will also result in an address that's a lot easier to remember than your IP.
3. Router config. For outside connections to reach your laptop, your home router will need to forward port 80 from your external IP (whatever your router has on its WAN interface) to the local IP on your laptop. Additionally, port 81 and/or 443 if implementing HTTPS.
4. (Optional) A domain name. If using a dynamic DNS provider, your domain will just be an alias for your dynDNS. If not, you create an A record for your home IP.

I'm afraid a more detailed answer would be very long, but now you know the basics and what to start reading up on.

---

**Security disclaimer:**
I feel obligated to mention that setting up a webserver, especially at home, especially on your primary laptop, can pose a security risk. If there's a flaw with your configuration, you run the risk of exposing everything on your laptop to a potential attacker, in addition to your laptops possible use as an intermediate step for access to the rest of your LAN. I'm not saying you shouldn't do this (hell, I did), but be aware of the risks.

Comment: Answer is pretty right.  May be time consuming.  I would note, though, that step 2 might be overcome-able.  Ask your ISP.  I know of one local ISP that will do this for free.  Others might charge, maybe as low as $5 per month.  Others may charge more.  Often, you can get an IPv4 /29, which comes with eight addresses (five of which are typically usable).  This can be easier, and sometimes more reliable, than the Dynamic DNS route.  What isn't good, though, is advertising your web site and then having the site go down.  If you can't do it right, then have a pro hosting company do it.

Comment: TCP port 81 is not the most commonly used port number for HTTPS.  TCP port 443 is.

Comment: @TOOGAM You are correct. Thanks for reminding me. Edited accordingly.